# I can not write integer in LCD AVR

Tags: avr

I can not write integer into the LCD using those functions :S it shows something weird in screen
I just added the function below!!! please check it for me
I added everything needed

```
    my_delay(1000);
        LCDWriteStringXY(0,0,"Welcome..");
        my_delay(1000);
        LCDWriteStringXY(0,0,"Welcome...");
        my_delay(1000);
            LCDClear();
            LCDWriteStringXY(4,0,"Testing");
            LCDGotoXY(2,1);

            int m=952520;
            LCDWriteInt(m,6);//I can not write it!!!

void LCDWriteInt(int val,unsigned int field_length)
{


    char str[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
    int i=4,j=0;
    while(val)
    {
    str[i]=val%10;
    val=val/10;
    i--;
    }
    if(field_length==-1)
        while(str[j]==0) j++;
    else
        j=5-field_length;

    if(val<0) LCDData('-');
    for(i=j;i<5;i++)
    {
    LCDData(48+str[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. What does your `LCDWriteInt` function look like? What LCD are you using? Does it have a datasheet? 8-bit or 32-bit? Just to give a few examples.

Comment: void LCDWriteInt(int val,unsigned int field_length)
{


 char str[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
 int i=4,j=0;
 while(val)
 {
 str[i]=val%10;
 val=val/10;
 i--;
 }
 if(field_length==-1)
  while(str[j]==0) j++;
 else
  j=5-field_length;

 if(val<0) LCDData('-');
 for(i=j;i<5;i++)
 {
 LCDData(48+str[i]);
 }
}

Comment: Again, is it an 8-bit part or a 32-bit part? That is, what is `sizeof(int)`? Either way, your value is too big, but the solution depends on the data size. How big is the largest number you need to write (absolute value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function is written for 16-bit integers for which the maximum value would be 65535 (5 digits - same as the length of str[]). You are giving it 6 digit value, which first overruns the string when it tries to write to str[5], and then produces j = -1.

My suggestion is to either use smaller integers (16-bit only), or write another function like the one you showed us to do the same thing for larger values.

Lastly, I don't know if the if(val<0) LCDData('-') would actually ever work properly since you overwrite 'val' in the first while loop.

Comment: If it's an 8-bit AVR, then the `int` is in fact 16 bits and the problem (the main one, anyway) is the line `int m=952520;`, though the compiler should at least warn about it. In that case, the data type would need to be changed to `long int` if the values actually can get that high.

Answer (score 0):

Use itoa function. That will help you converting integer to string and displaying on lcd. Best of luck!